# What is the scope of a class declaration in C++?

Tags: c++, class, scope, declaration

What is the scope of a class declaration? In particular: if I declare a class in a source file, is it within the global scope or the translation unit scope or other?  Also... How do I declare a class only in the scope of the translation unit, like a static variable?

(for example: can I declare a class in some source file without having to worry about accidentally accessing it in my main source file?)

Comment: Please make your question self contained, links to code aren't appropriate here

Comment: Non-language-lawyer answer:  If in the CPP / CXX it is only visible within that CPP / CXX.  If in the H then is only visible to the CPP where implemented and anything that includes the H.  That's the answer for every C++ compiler I've used since Borland's DOS one.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It's links to cppreference,com, why is that bad? I thought it added context. I'll remove it if it's bad.

Comment: If you're worried about name collisions you can always use a namespace.

Comment: @user4581301 my compiler says: `'static' is not permitted on a declaration of a type`. And it is not true for all declarations; for example the `using` keyword is only visible in the scope of the translation unit (the file) although that is a bit of a special case. (btw, please tell me what is unclear in the question).

Comment: My apologies. I misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of a class is the namespace where the class is declared. If it is declared in the global namespace, then the class is global.

A class must be defined in every translation unit that ODR-use the class. All TUs that refer to a class name always refer to the same class, not a TU specific class. The definition of a class must be identical across all TUs.

> How do I declare a class only in the scope of the translation unit

You can use an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace {
    struct this_TU_only {
        int member;
    };
}
```

Defining following class in another TU would not be a problem:

```
namespace {
    struct this_TU_only {
        float member;
    };
}
```

This is because an unnamed namespace is distinct in each translation unit.

Comment: Perfect answer, do you have any reference for the first part of the answer? +1 for the unnamed namespace!

Comment: The first part seems to not be true in general. Compiling for example `g++ someclass.cc main.cc` where `main.cc` instantiates an object of a class defined in `someclass.cc` results in compiler error ...`was not declared in this scope`. Defining the class in `main.cc` and then trying to use it in `someclass.cc` gives the same error. Also trying to link them in opposite order gives the same result.

Comment: Now that I read your answer again, I think I might have missunderstood it at first... Do you mean that a class must explicitly be defined in every TU or do you mean that it is always defined implicitly in every TU?

Comment: @dekuShrub `Do you mean that a class must explicitly be defined in every TU ` Yes (every TU that ODR-use the class).